# $nth$ derivative of function on $\mathbb R^2$: chain rule or binomial polynomial?

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

Let $f(x,y)$ be a real valued function defined in an open subset of $\mathbb R^2$.
Prove that
$$\frac{d^n}{dt^n}f(a+ht,b+kt) = \left( h\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+ k\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)^nf$$
where $a,b,h,k$ are constants.

I was looking for the shortest way to prove this. If I set for example $$l(t) = f(a+ht,b+kt)$$
one is tempted to do things like $(l(t)^m)' = ml(t)^{m-1}l'(t)$  but I believe this is not possible since $l(t)$ is a composition involving a $2$ variable function, right?

So I am only thinking on using a binomial expresion and using induction.

Any other idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letting $f(a+ht,b+kt)=f(x(t),y(t))$. By chain rule, we have
$$\frac{df}{dt}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{dy}{dt}= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}h+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}k.$$
Applying it again, we see the pattern we want emerge
$$ \begin{align*} 
\frac{d^2f}{dt^2} = \frac{d}{dt} \left( \frac{df}{dt} \right) &= \frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left( \frac{df}{dt} \right) \frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial }{\partial y} \left( \frac{df}{dt} \right) \frac{dy}{dt} \\
&= h^2 \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} + 2hk \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x}+k^2 \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}
\end{align*}$$
which kind of makes it clear that induction is sort of the straightforward case. Regardless of the path taken, we'll be proving this holds for $\forall n \in \mathbb N$, which means induction is needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If we assume this is valid for $m$ and we have $\frac{d^m}{dt^m}f = \left( h\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+ k\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)^mf$  why is not correct to say that $\frac{d^{m+1}}{dt^{m+1}}f = m\left( h\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+ k\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)^{m-1}\left( h\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+ k\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)^2 f$ ? or is it valid to apply that derivation rule in this case?

Comment: @mate89 Like you stated above, the problem just comes down to it having two variables. In treating $f(a+ht,b+kt)$ as just $l(t)$, you're ignoring that $x(t)=a+ht$ and $y(t)=b+kt$ are themselves impacted.